# Resize Div/Element dynamically based on calculated RNG

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a script that allows me to click a button on the page and then the JS function linked to it will generate a random number between 1-1000 and be set as the dimensions of the div. Chrome inspector shows that the attribute changes are taking place, but the content on the page itself doesn't change.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="block" style="background-color:blue;">
</div>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("block").setAttribute("width", Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001) + "px" );
document.getElementById("block").setAttribute("height", Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001) + "px" );
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NR2k6/118/

Comment: Why don't you use `element.style.width` instead of `setAttribute`?

Comment: Only a small number of HTML elements use width & height attributes for sizing, eg. `img` & `canvas`. You should use css by setting the `style` attribute instead for `divs`

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `style` of the element, not the attribute:

```
var d = document.getElementById("block");
d.style.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001) + "px" ;
d.style.height= Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001) + "px" ;
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I was trying to use .style first but it wasn't working, maybe I had incorrectly entered the code. Seriously though, thanks. I'm going to get hours of amusement out of clicking this button now

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey this is the correct answer, I have updated your fiddle as a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/NR2k6/119/